# Android 10 storage ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-storage, scoped-storage

```
private fun createOutputFile(fileNumber: Int): File {
    val directoryPath =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .toString() + File.separator + FOLDER_NAME

    val file = File(directoryPath)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir()
    }

    val outputPath = directoryPath + File.separator + createFileName(fileNumber)

    return File(outputPath)
}
```

This code working on Android 11 and Android 9.

On Android 10 it throws `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.
With `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` it works.

I want to get rid of `requestLegacyExternalStorage`, can someone explain why it is works on Android 11 and not works on Android 10? What is the difference?

Permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted.

Comment: Start with changing `if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir()
    }` to `if (!file.exists()) {
        if ( !file.mkdirs() ) return;
    }` Display a Toast too to inform the user in case mkdirs() fails.

Comment: `It is needed for 10 and only used for 10` and what about Android 9?

Comment: It is not needed for devices which are not version 10. And it harms nobody.

Comment: This is really confusing, it works on Android 9 and 11 but not work on 10 without `requestLegacyExternalStorage`, if "requestLegacyExternalStorage" is true on Android 10, so I am working with legacy storage like Android 9, no? I really lost in the storage system

Comment: I dont understand why you make a problem out of it. YOU HAVE TO USE IT if you want your app to run on an Android 10 device. There is nothing more in it. Take a break.

Comment: Just want to understand what is the story behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I want to get rid of requestLegacyExternalStorage

No. No. No.

Why would you?

There is no alternative.

Leave it!

It is needed for 10 and only used for 10 devices.

You have to put it in manifest if you want to use that code on an Android 10 device.